# Prompt to replace empty cells with user-defined text

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA code to check for blank cells within a range. If there are any blanks within that range, a box should come up to allow you to type in what you want to replace the blanks with. The code below does what I want, but the prompt ALWAYS appears, even if there aren't any blanks. How do I make it so the box only appears if there are blanks?

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()
  Dim Lastrow As Integer
  Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Range("D84:D" & Lastrow).Select
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim InputValue As String
  On Error Resume Next
  InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", "Fill Empty Cells")
  For Each cell In Selection
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
      cell.Value = InputValue
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Properly indenting your code will help make your code easier to read/follow - for you and anyone else looking at it. Anything between `For` and `Next` needs a TAB; anything between `If` and `End If` needs a TAB; anything between `Sub` and `End Sub` needs a TAB.

Comment: Do you want **one** value to fill all cells? Or, for each empty cell, could it be a different `InputValue`?

Comment: @BruceWayne One value to fill all blank cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim srchRng As Range

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set srchRng = Range(Cells(84, 4), Cells(Lastrow, 4))

Dim InputValue As String

If srchRng.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountA(srchRng) > 0 Then
    InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", _
                          "Fill Empty Cells")
    srchRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = InputValue
End If
End Sub
```

This also adds in the range variable, so you [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). It also assumes that you only want ONE inputvalue. If you want it to trigger for each empty cell, put the `inputValue = ...` in the `If IsEmpty(cell)` loop.

An alternative to your `If a cell is empty` loop, is a one line fix:

`Range(Cells(84,4),Cells(lastRow,4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = InputValue`.  That will take ALL blanks in `D84:DlastRow` and fill in with whatever the `InputValue` is.  No need to loop.

Comment: This works but if no blanks it will throw and error (which I see you error handled).  Using total count minus countA will never error even with no blanks so I took out the error handling (I like to avoid error handling as much as possible).

Comment: @Robby - I updated the code, removing the Error handler, and the extra (now unused) `Cell` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("D84:D" & Lastrow).Select
Dim cell As Range
Dim InputValue As String
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In Selection
If IsEmpty(cell) Then
InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", _
"Fill Empty Cells")
cell.Value = InputValue
End If
Next
End Sub
```

just move the line to the right place :D

Comment: But then he has to go a box at a time.  I think he wants to fill all empties with one entry.

Comment: if so , it is easy : add "if InputValue = "" then " before InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", _
"Fill Empty Cells")

Answer (score 1):

`YourRange.Cells.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountA(YourRange)` will give you the count of blanks so you can check if you have blanks:

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()
    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'Use 4 as it is the D column you are working with

    Dim cel As Range 'Use cel as CELL can be confused with functions
    Dim InputValue As String
    If Range("D84:D" & Lastrow).Cells.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D84:D" & Lastrow)) > 0 Then
        InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", "Fill Empty Cells")
        For Each cel In Range("D84:D" & Lastrow)
            If IsEmpty(cel) Then
                cel.Value = InputValue
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```